# Add a custom shape to a Maya scene from C++

Tags: c++, maya, autodesk

I'm in the process of creating a custom import plugin for maya. I already wrote some import code and created a custom `MPxSurfaceShape` class (I'm mainly interested in drawing the surface from within the viewport).

The shape gets crated by a `MPxCommand` which reads a file from the disk. Now I would like to add this object to my maya scene from within the plugin. But unfortunately I can't find a function that takes a `MPxNode`/`MPxSurfaceShape` and adds it to Maya so that it can be displayed.

In all examples I've seen the node is instantiated from within mel. But I want to link this instance a file. Which prevents me from just creating the node and then editing it.

A similar solution might be found in either the `apiMeshShape` example in the maya plugin folder or here: https://github.com/ADN-DevTech/Maya-Locator/ (also supports the loading of external data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I hope will help.

```
 MDagModifier dagMod;
 MObject newNode = dagMod.MDGModifier::createNode("Node Name")
 dagMod.doIt()
```

or

```
 MDagModifier dagMod;
 MObject newNode = dagMod.MDGModifier::createNode(Node::id)
 dagMod.doIt()
```

From there you have an MObject you can make into other things.

```
 //Dag Node example.
 MFnDagNode new_MDagNode(newNode);

 //Dependency Node.
 MFnDependencyNode new_DependNode(newNode);
```

The MPxNode also has thisMObject() which will give you the current MObject in the MPxNode.
http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/API/class_m_px_node.html#9608c582da0945e792c3f9893661404d

Again I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I think I should better start from scratch. I think I need to restructure the plugin: The `apiMeshShape` example looks very similar to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks! I also found the https://github.com/ADN-DevTech/Maya-Locator/ with the customLocator node which essentially does what I want.

Comment: Accepting the solution, since my question is ambiguous and solutions can be found on the web.